# Regarding regular expression in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, macos

I am working on regular expressions but where ever I search I am getting the code and explanation for validating the email now I have to do something like this

Contents of the file are like this(file formate may be .rtf, .txt ...etc)

`[Title:languageC]
[Author:Dennis Ritchie]
[Description:this book is nice to learn the C language]`

form this file now I want to extract the languageC,  Dennis Ritchie,  this book is nice to learn the C language.  I have achieved this by using NSStrings, NSScanner and NSRange but now I want to achieve this same using regularexpressions is it possible.

Comment: See [`NSRegularExpression`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html). And if  you google it or search here, I'm sure the question has been asked and answered many, many times. If you try it and have some problems, show us your code and we'll be happy to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *regexStr = @"\[Title:([.]+)\][ ]+\[Author:([.]+)\][ ]+\[Description:([.]+)\]";

NSError *error;
NSRegularExpression *testRegex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:regexStr options:0 error:&error];

if( testRegex == nil ) NSLog( @"Error making regex: %@", error );

NSTextCheckingResult *result = [testRegex firstMatchInString:test options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [test length])];

NSRange range = [result rangeAtIndex:1]; // This will give you Title,
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a regex like this:

```
/\[[^:]+:([^]])\]/
```

E.g.:

```
NSError *error;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\[[^:]+:([^]])\]" options:0 error:&error];
NSArray* matches = [regex matchesInString:YOUR_STR options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [YOUR_STRING length]);
```